# rapid background change upon prompt answer

Tags: javascript, html

I am a noob here in JS and I am doing my homework making a simple color guessing game. So far everything works as far as the criteria goes.

My only problem is that I can't figure out how to make it so that the background changes instantly upon user input (Right after clicking [OK] at the Prompt). As of now with the code below, the background changes only after clicking [OK] in the Congrats alert..I am pretty sure it's possible because my prof showed in the lecture an example he did where the background color changed right after guessing the correct color!

Also, it would be nice if any pros out there could give me suggestions on polishing my code. I have a feeling that it is messy and too complex than what its trying to achieve..Heh..

PS: I know that js logic should be separated in the page but my prof insisted we do this exercise with the script inline!

Thank you!

```html
<body onload="doGame()">
    <script>
        var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var target;
        var answer;
        var guessInputText;
        var guessInput;
        var finished = false;
        var guessAmount = 0;
        var colors = ['Salmon', 'Tomato', 'Moccasin', 'Peru', 'Olive', 'Teal', 'Navy', 'Thistle', 'Beige', 'Gray'];
        var colorsSorted = colors.sort();
        var colorsSortedString = colors.join(', ');

        function doGame() {
            var randomColorNum = Math.random() * 10;
            var randomColorNumInt = Math.floor(randomColorNum);
            target = colors[randomColorNumInt + 1];
            answer = target.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + target.slice(1).toLowerCase(); //makes sure answer is in lowercase
            alert("The answer is " + target + " or " + answer); //for debugging

            while(!finished) {
                guessInputText = prompt('I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n' +
                                        colorsSortedString + '\n\n' +
                                        'What color am I thinking of?');
                guessInput = guessInputText.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + guessInputText.slice(1).toLowerCase(); //converts whatever input into lowercase
                guessAmount += 1;
                finished = checkGuess(); //checks to see if user input is correct
            }
        }

        function checkGuess() {
            if ((colors.indexOf(guessInputText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + guessInputText.slice(1).toLowerCase()) > -1) == false) {
                alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color.\n\n" +
                        "Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            if (guessInput > answer) {
                alert("Sorry, Your guess is incorrect!\n\n" +
                        "Hint: Your color is alphabetically higher than mine.\n\n" +
                        "Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            if (guessInput < answer) {
                alert("Sorry, Your guess is incorrect!\n\n" +
                        "Hint: Your color is alphabetically lower than mine.\n\n" +
                        "Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
                myBody.style.background = answer;
                alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\n" +
                        "It took you " + guessAmount + " guesses to finish the game!\n\n" +
                        "You can see the color in the background.");
                return true;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the background before the [OK] on congrats prints, you just have to move this line

```
myBody.style.background = answer;
```

But.. Testing your snippet, the background change right after I press OK on the guess color prompt.

So what do you want exactly ? Can you give us an example step by step ?

Comment: Thanks for answering! That's interesting, I'm using Chrome and when I open this exact file, the bg doesn't change until I click [OK] on the Congrats alert what I want to happen is that upon entering the correct answer, the bg should change at the same time as your getting  the Congrats Alert

Comment: I figured adding setTimeOut would help relating the Congrats alert and set the bg to change before the Congrats alert shows up!